# iTextSharp list bullet - bullet colour bug?

Tags: itext

I'm trying to use iTextSharp to produce some auto-generated PDF flyers of marketing material based on HTML content stored in a database.  Its working really well, but I've found something I think might be a bug in iTextSharp.

I start with a block of HTML that might contain regular HTML lists like:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

I run the block of HTML through HTMLWorker.ParseToList to get a list of the parsed items ready to add to the PDF.

With lists, our corporate style is to have the text in black, but the bullet point in blue.  So I run through the list of elements and find those which are Lists, and set the colour of the symbol to be blue:

```
List<IElement> elementsList = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(strHtml), style);

for(int cnt = 0; cnt < elementsList.Count; cnt++)
{
    IElement element = (IElement)elementsList[cnt];
    if (element is List)
    {
       List l = (List)element;
       l.Symbol.Font.Color = new BaseColor(26, 189, 201);
       /* then code here which adds the list to the output column */
    } 
    else
    {
       /* code which adds the element without any extra processing */
    }
}
```

This works perfectly, only the blue colour is also applied to the text of the last item in the list (not just the bullet).  As I say, only the last item in the list is affected.  The other items output perfectly with blue bullet points, and black text.  I can't post a picture apparently, but I've linked to a PNG below:

[[click to see the problem]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QocuN.png)

Just wondered if anyone had come across this before, and if so, whether there was a work around.  I've tested with the latest version of iTextSharp, to make sure I'm up-to-date.

Is setting List.Symbol.Font.Color the correct way to do it?  I assume so because it works for all the elements of the list, just not the very last one!

Thanks,

Steve.

Comment: No work is or has been done with the `HTMLWorker` in a long time. Instead you are encouraged to upgrade to the `XMLWorker`.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll need to look in to upgrading my code to use XMLWorker.  I think the code samples I found when researching the topic a while back used HTMLWorker - no particular reason for sticking with it providing XMLWorker works at least as good.  I solved the problem for now by creating a new iTextSharp.text.List object each time I encounter an HTMLWorker generated list, and copy over the content and style information from one to the other.  Bizarrely, the coloured bullet points then work correctly.